# Can I use background threads on Google App Engine Standard + Python 3?

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine

The [GAE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) is vague about support for background threads in the Standard environment:

[image]

Here is an example code I'm trying to run with no success. I'm trying to figure out if the issue is in the code or it's just not supported.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
executor.submit(my_func, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.result()` so your HTTP request blocks until `my_func()` completes? eg:

```py
future = executor.submit(my_func, *args, **kwargs)
future.result()
```

[Circa 2014, back in the original Python 2 runtime,](https://snarfed.org/how-many-app-engine-background-threads-can-run-in-parallel) App Engine distinguished between "background" threads, which could continue running after the HTTP request completed, and "normal" threads, which couldn't. I don't know whether/how that's changed in the current Python 3 runtime, but it might still cut off "normal" threads when the request completes.